# Items in the list are being replaced by the last item added to the list

Tags: java

### Here I am adding different objects to the list,but while retrieving the list i'm getting the contents of the object which is added at last

```
 @Override
        public String ConfirmOrder(OrderBean orderBean, ArrayList<CartBean> cartbean) {
            String response = "FAIL";
            OrderBean obean=null;
            try {
                ArrayList<OrderBean> list = new ArrayList<OrderBean>();

                orderBean.setOrderDate(new Date());
                orderBean.setOrderStatus("Pending");
                Iterator<CartBean> it = cartbean.iterator();
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    CartBean type = (CartBean) it.next();
                    orderBean.setCartID(type.getCartID());
                    orderBean.setTotalPrice(type.getCost());
                    System.out.println("setting the cart id and price :"+type.getCartID()+" : "+type.getCost());//checking the items which were inserted into the object
                    obean=null;//setting the object to null every time 
                    obean=orderBean;
                    list.add(obean);
                    System.out.println("Cart count :");
                }
                //iterating the list
                for(OrderBean ob:list)
                {
                    System.out.println("cartid :"+ob.getCartID());
                }
}


here is the console output
```

setting the cart id and price :1000 : 100.0
    Cart count :
    setting the cart id and price :1001 : 90.0
    cart count :
    setting the cart id and price :1002 : 825.0
    Cart count :
    setting the cart id and price :1003 : 1210.0
    Cart count :

iterating the same list
   cartid :1003
   cartid :1003
   cartid :1003
   cartid :1003

Comment: _Here I am adding different objects to the list_ Why do you think so?

Answer (score 1):

It's because , you are not all creating an object. You are keep on modifying the existing one

```
 while (it.hasNext()) {
                    CartBean type = (CartBean) it.next();
                    orderBean.setCartID(type.getCartID()); // here
```

Actually you need to create an `orderbean` object each time in the loop and then add it to loop. As of now you keep on modifying single object.